# What is wrong about this query?

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this query? I can't seem to figure it out and have been banging my head for the last hour.

```
$qry = "UPDATE UserServices SET Username='$newusername', Password='$newpassword', GivenName='$servicename' WHERE UserID='$userid' AND ServiceID='$service' AND Add='$add'";
$result = mysql_query($qry) or die("An error occurred ".mysql_error());
```

Comment: What mysql_error() say?

Comment: Try adding error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 7):

ADD is a reserved keyword and you need to backtick it as

```
`Add`
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Here are some usage of `add` in mysql so using this as column or table name will raise error, unless you backtick it while using it for tablename or column name.

```
alter table foo add index ...
alter table foo add column...
```

etc

Answer (score 2):

`add` is a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Wrap the word using backticks or choose another word.

```
AND `Add`='$add'"
```

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Error reporting links:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.